# Why does my ProgressDialog exit when I click on Activity?

Tags: android

I am showing a ProgressDialog using the following code:

```
void showProccess() {    
    p = new ProgressDialog(this);
    p.setTitle("PleaseWait");                   
    p.setMessage("data loading");
    p.show();
}
```

In Android 2.3.1 when a `ProgressDialog` is shown, I can't click on the `Activity`. But in Android 4.0.3, I click on `Activity` and the `ProgressDialog` will exit.
I want the `ProgressDialog` to not exit, the same as Android 2.3.1.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried giving p.setCancelable(false);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set the following:

```
 p.setCancelable(false);
```

By this , progress dialog can not be cancelled.

Answer (score 4):

Try the fllowing code along with your existing code,

```
p.setCancelable(false);
```